# SImple proof based on Inequalities

Tags: inequality

In a right-angled $\triangle ABC$, which is right-angled at $C$, prove that $a^n + b^n < c^n$
for all $n > 2$.

---

I am able to prove this for  powers of 2
as $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

$$(a^2 + b^2)^n > (a^2)^n + (b^2)^n$$
But how to prove that it's true for all $n$ int.s

Comment: Try to divide by $c^2$. Then use trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $0<\frac{a}{c}<1$ and $0<\frac{b}{c}<1$, one has for $n>2$:

$$\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^n+\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^n<\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^2=1$$